# Schengen visa without entering country that issued visa

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, spain, norway

I am a Chinese national living in the UK. I applied to a Spain Schengen visa but to my dismay and contrary to what I expected, I only got 1 entry to the Schengen area for my visa. I have to completely rethink my travel plans.

I am now thinking of going to Norway and then going back to the UK directly ( the UK is outside the Schengen area ). It means that I won't go to Spain at all with my Spain visa. Will it affect my ability to apply for another Spain visa in the future ? Is it a problem if I enter Norway without going to Spain first ?

Comment: It is common place, often for first time applicants, for an single entry visa to be issued if you told them that you were planning a single visit to Spain. Had you told them that you were planning 5 days in Norway and then later 10 days in Spain, then they may have issued a dual entry visa. Multi entry visas are only issued when, based in previous visits, if you are considered reliable. If you keep to your plan, it is unlikly they will think that you are reliable while processing your next visa application.

Comment: @MarkJohnson not only that, but they may reject them on entry into Norway if they are attempting to enter on a Spanish-issued Schengen visa and there is no discernible plan to fly from Norway to Spain for the bulk of the Schengen visit...

Comment: What was the itinerary you submitted with your application? How come if your visit to Spain was the main reason for travel you’d rather ditch that rather than Norway? Do you have enough time to apply for a separate visa for Norway? (Note I’m not saying this is necessarily what you should do, just trying to understand the situation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These things are decided on a case to case basis and there is no universal answer. I know people who didn't go at all to the issuing country and then had no problem in getting another visa and I also know someone who were denied entry. It all comes down to how the border officer perceives your intent. There can be genuine change in travel plans and can be acceptable. It is very much possible that the border officer at the Norway airport doesn't ask you anything and just says "enjoy your stay" and it is also possible that they extensively ask about your travel plans and want to know why don't you have Spain in your plan if you applied for a Spanish visa. It is very much possible that get convinced by your answer and grant you entry and it is also possible that they deny you entry. Every case and every instance is different.

You mentioned that "you have to completely rethink your travel plans" because you got a single entry visa. Did the plans which you submitted with the visa application involved an exit and re-entry from the Schengen area? If the proposed plan didn't involve a re-entry in the Schengen area, then then why do you have to change plans now?

The whole thing is your call. You should have a convincing and genuine explanation for a change in plans in case you are asked. Keep in mind, even if you decide to enter through Spain, the border officer can still ask to your plans, hotel bookings etc and can still ask that why you are spending more days in Norway as compared to Spain. Luck also plays a big factor here.